# ubuntu linux shell scripting with command line grep and split delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

i have this line :

```
S=`cut -d: -f4 | grep $name info.txt`;
```

then i display by

```
echo "$S";
```

It display nothing.

`grep $name info.txt`;` gives me output :

```
Francis:8:98765432:commission // this is a line from my textfile separated by :
```

i am trying to display `comission` only

Comment: try `grep $name info.txt | cut -d: -f4` .. what this means is that output of `grep` is fed as input to `cut`.. the one you tried should have given some error or waiting for further input..

Comment: see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial for further reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also work

```
    echo 'Francis:8:98765432:commission' | cut -d: -f4
```

Comment: hi sorry i forgot to mention what if without hard coding the text? i tried echo "$S" | cut -d: -f4 , don't work

Comment: If you try this way    S="Francis:8:98765432:commission";echo "$S" | cut -d: -f4.    It works for me.

Comment: thanks it work , but i wonder why it won't work it like the 1 i posted in my question

Answer (score 0):

Use awk?

```
awk -F: -v name="$name" '$0 ~ name { print $4 }'
```

Or flip the pipe?

```
cut -d: -f4 < info.txt | grep "$name"
```